# Why would only some js libraries load in with Symfony2/Twig?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, assetic

Attempting to load in multiple js libraries.  Using either method bellow, the bootstrap and facebook js files load in fine, but any other libraries I add either throw a 500 error if called by name or simply do not load in if using /*  The files are all in the same directory with the same permissions as far as I can tell.  Why would this be happening and how can I fix it?

Method 1:

```
{% javascripts
        'bundles/onnbrun/js/*'
        %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Method 2:

```
{% javascripts
        'bundles/onnbrun/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'
        'bundles/onnbrun/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.js'
        'bundles/onnbrun/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        'bundles/onnbrun/js/facebook_enable.js'
        %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

UPDATE #1:

Using the @Bundle syntax suggested below I am able to run php app/console assetic:dump without error; however, when I attempt to go to app_dev.php in a browser I get the error:

An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@ONNBrunBundle/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js".") in "ONNBrunBundle::web.html.twig".

I am able to view the file located in my bundle's Resources/public/js directory through my ide and through putty.

UPDATE #2:

On advice from lee in #symfony tried routing to my js directory in my browser and voila! only the two js files that have been serving properly the whole time are there - nothing else.

So... /www/src/ONN/BrunBundle/Resources/public/js shows me all the js files I'm trying to serve when I look at it through putty or through my ide or through any random ftp program; however, /web/bundles/onnbrun/js/ in a browser shows only the two js files that serve correctly.

I have run assetic:dump and assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug with no errors.

I have run cache:clear.

I don't know what could be causing the discrepancy.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: try clearing the cachce and then try again

Comment: Have you dumped all of them? `app/console assetic:dump`

Comment: when I do the dump I get [error] The source file "/home/brun/www/app/../web/bundles/onnbrun/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" does not exist.  but I see the file in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**case 1)**

your files are stored in a bundle

If it's the case, use the code below

```
{% javascripts
        '@YourBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
        %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

**case 2)**

Your files are stored in your root web directory under a js directory (not a bundle directory)

```
{% javascripts
        'js/*'
        %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

**Final step**

dump your file

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: When using the @Bundle syntax there's basically no change.  Obviously no error is thrown at dump if I use --no-debug, but if I just run php app/console assetic:dump it says: [RuntimeException]
  The source file "/home/brun/www/app/../web/bundles/onnbrun/js/jquery-1.8.0.
  min.js" does not exist.  And attempting to go to the template in a browser produces the error: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@ONNBrunBundle/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js".") in "ONNBrunBundle::web.html.twig

Comment: I needed to be running php app/console cache:clear between each trouble shooting attempt - that's probably half my problem.  When I use the @Bundle syntax then clear the cache and then try php app/console assetic:dump it runs clean, but then I still get the Unable to find file error when attempting to go to the template in a browser.  Why?

Comment: The two working files were a red herring; they weren't really being served by assetic, they'd been plugged in manually months ago.  redid the whole thing, works beautifully now.

Comment: great,  be sure to dump assetics on prod, you dont need on dev (by default)

Comment: Your explanation on both cases was exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you!